# How can i set the Value of a Variable as an ID in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following code:

```
var counter = 0; //counter variable
    $('#divfuerimage').on('click', function(evt){
    counter= counter+1; //count up
    alert(counter);
    var containerX = evt.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
        containerY = evt.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

    $('<div class="child" id=/*here the value of counter should be*/></div>')
```

How can I use the Value of my Counter Variable as an ID?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition.

Comment: `$('<div class="child" id=' + counter +'/></div>')`

Comment: Your premise is flawed: all-numeric `id` attributes are invalid in HTML4.1 and lower. They're valid in HTML5, but not in CSS3, so you cannot reliably match them.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Incorrect, you can match them in CSS3: `[id="44"]`

Comment: why all of this downvotes? seems like a legit question no?

Comment: @FelixLahmer The question itself is not not legitim, but maybe the reasons are "RTFM" and that you simply could have tried string concatenation. (I didn't down vote I'm just guessing)

Comment: @wumm obviously yeah, I am fairly new to Jquery and am trying to get some hands on experience. I honestly tried a lot like adding with ++ forgot the '' or just writing counter or escaped it... slowly I udnerstand why total newbs get mad of SO fast

Comment: @wumm, not *reliably*. [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) is explicit about it: *identifiers* (element names, classes and ids) must not start with a number (among other limitations). Any given CSS engine may enforce that rule even in attribute selectors like `[id="44"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concatenate the string or create an element like this.

```
$('<div>',{
   "class":"child",
   "id": counter
});
```

Comment: oh cool, a solution that solved my other problem aswell, thank you one more time :))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('<div class="child" id="'+counter+'"></div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div class="child" id="'+counter+'"></div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate the variable like this:

```
$('<div class="child" id="'+coutner+'"></div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating like this:

```
$('<div class="child" id='+counter+'></div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div>',{
   "class":"child",
   "id": counter
}).appendTo("#targetContainer");
```

Comment: Typo: `,` is wrong on the third line, there should be a `:`