# HTML as output JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the last Question I asked, about alerting Variables out.

Can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602954/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-variable-as-an-id-in-jquery).

I fixed it and it works now.

With the knowledge I gained from the last answers I wanted to do an output of an `<a> </a>`
with Variables in it.

But am not able to do this.

I did try various types of escaping which came to my mind. None Helped.

So I´m going to ask you guys again: How can I fix this, to print out my Variables correctly?

```
$('<a>'
ID von '' + counter + ''
XPosition '' + containerX + '', YPosition '' + ContainerY '</a>').appendTo($('#textuelledarstellung'));
```

Context:

```
var counter = 0;
$('#divfuerimage').on('click', function (evt) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    var containerX = evt.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
    containerY = evt.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
    alert('ID von' + counter + ' XPosition' + containerX + ''
                               , YPosition' + containerY); //this is working

    $('<a>'
    ID von '' + counter + ''
    XPosition '' + containerX + '', YPosition '' + ContainerY '</a>').appendTo($('#textuelledarstellung'));
            //this not
```

Comment: Please format and rephrase your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create element using jQuery and use its method to set your data.

Use

```
var htmlText = 'ID von' + counter + ' XPosition' + containerX + ', YPosition' + containerY;
$('<a></a>')
    .prop('id', YourId)
    .prop('href', Url)
    .html(htmlText)
    .appendTo($('#textuelledarstellung'));
```

Comment: This is the proper way to handle inserting HTML Using jQuery. If you use string concatenation, you'll likely end up having a monster of a string that is hard to maintain and difficult to add another property to.. If you use the method above, it's trivial to add another property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $link = $("<a>", {
   "id" : "elementID",                 // <a id="elementID"></a>
   "class" : "elementClass",           // <a class="elementClass"></a>
   "href" : "http:...",                // <a href="http:..."></a>
   "html" : "<span>Text</span>",       // <a><span>text</span></a>
   "text" : "Hello World" + " !",      // <a>Hello world</a> - this will replace previus HTML  
});

$("body").append($link);
```

This will output:

```
<a id="elementID" class="elementClass" href="http:...">Hello World !</a>
```

Comment: this is totally not what i want

Comment: this is just different way to create a HREF with any properties :)